API changes after Jenkins Core Version 2.462.2.2 upgrade
We are storing queueId from Jenkins API as integer as it used to be. However after Jenkins version upgrade to CloudBees CI Version 2.462.2.2, this queueId becomes a really big number like 59214986632345984610 which is exceed the integer size and caused an error. Is it an expected change in this particular version? My understanding is queueId is a regular primary key, why it setup as a large number in this new version?

queueId has always been long, check git blame here, for example. So it should be between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,808. I am going to assume the example you provided is a bit of an exaggeration. If not - could you provide the API endpoint that returned it?

thank you, yes that number was exaggerative but the real number we got is exceed integer size for sure. I did some research and find out it has something to do with HA enabled along with the upgraded version, but thank you again for the data type you clarified.
